# How to integrate Angular2 with Java

Tags: java, angular, jetty, dropwizard

I am working on dropwizard and angular2. both are working fine in different server. I want to integrate angular2 with java so that they can work on single server. I have tried [tomitribe/weekler](https://github.com/tomitribe/weekler) but when I did, mvn clean package it gives error. Any one have tried angular2 with java.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example of Java and Angular 2 integration:
http://lteconsulting.fr/angular2boot/ .

Demo app here: https://github.com/ltearno/angular2-gwt .

The way it's different from JHipster is that you have also Angular2 frontend in Java.
As you see this is also Angular 2 dependent.

If about the server side... You have by default Spring Boot integration. But you can of course use it with any Java backend, like JavaEE with JAX-RS Web services or whatever else.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yeah, way better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you some examples of Java + Angular but they use the Spring Framework.  Should be easy enough to port to Dropwizard.

- **[JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/)**
- **[Spring + Angular](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) | [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js)**
- **[Spring Cloud Online Store](https://github.com/kbastani/spring-cloud-event-sourcing-example/tree/master/online-store-web)**

Comment: all are angular1 project

Comment: The answer to your question doesn't depend on the particular version of Angular.  What you need to focus on is getting your frontend resources processed and then included in a directory like src/main/resources for example which will then be bundled into your jar/war and served by your controllers.  The links above demonstrate such project structures.  JHipster for example has already been refactored to support Angular2 when it becomes stable so the structure shouldn't change. https://jhipster.github.io/2016/03/23/jhipster-release-3.0.0.html

Comment: I would suggest sharing a sample project on GitHub of your integration thus far so we can provide better guidance.